# Suddenly cannot run/compile java program

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Everything worked perfectly until I had to brute-force restart notebook with opened java project ( 1 java class which was compiled ). After the reboot i opened intellij created a new project ( the old was not saved ) , then in src folder created a java class but whenever I want to Run it I get only `"Edit the configuration"` and do not know what to do.

Also when i write some piece of code like:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add( "Example" );
  }
}
```

The add method is red and it says `Cannot resolve the symbol add().`

This happens with every method even to `System.out.println()`

I will be very thankful for your suggestions. ( Btw I'm using intellij ultimate version, Linux Mint 17 ).

Comment: `new String<String>();` makes no sense. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: typo mistake i fixed it. It does for every single method even System.out.println

Comment: It sounds like your project SDK is not configured

Comment: It actually is configured i checked project structure there's SDK:  1.8 version of java jdk

Comment: Are you in an Intellij Java project, or did you just open a Java file using the IDE and expect to run it?

Comment: I'm in intellij project

Answer (score 0):

Please read compiler messages more carefully.

```
List<String> list = new String<String>();
```

Doesnt work - try:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

for example!

So, the **real** lesson here is not that you made a little typo. It is about the fact that you can trust on compiler error messages to a high degree! So, before you think "is my project broken"; you look at your source code and any error message **really really** carefully.

Comment: That's not the problem i made mistake because i did not copy the code it says that error message for every method and can't compile anything my jdk is set to 8

Comment: Well, worth a try. In that case ... I would try to get rid of existing projects, existing workspaces, and so on. In other words: throw things out, and create a new. Start with the small things where you don't loose anything; but if anything else fails; you might end up re-installing the whole stack there. Few chances that such "work env corrupted" will be get helpful answers here. Another hint: try posting in the IntelliJ forums.

Answer (score 0):

Stop Intellij, remove the .idea folder and .iml file from the directory, then restart.  You'll have to create a new project from the code, but it should work.  If you continue to have problems, go to the File menu and selected "Invalidate caches/restart".  Choose "Invalidate and restart."

Comment: I get the feeling that the JDK is not set correctly in the Intellij settings.  Did you look at the global settings to make sure it's pointed to the right place?